# nvidia driver problem unknown display

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution

I turned on my computer today and whereas before it displayed at 1920x1080 resolution using the NVidia driver now it runs at a much lower resolution and Settings says "unknown display".

I was notified of a software update and upon trying to apply it I get this:

[image: Software Updater error message]

I tried installing the open source nouveau driver instead but it keeps going back to the NVidia driver:

[image: Additional drivers window]

When I click the Nouveau driver and click Apply Changes it displays a progress bar but at the end the NVidia driver shows as selected.

I hadn't installed any new software on this machine leading up to this problem. It was working fine yesterday and this just happened today when I powered the PC up.

Next day after reading below suggestions:

The following commands appear to have succeeded:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

but the `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390` failed with unmet dependencies:

```
jeff@haran-linux:~$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-ifr1-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-driver-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-dkms-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Depends: libnvidia-compute-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-390:i386 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-390:i386 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-390:i386 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
jeff@haran-linux:~$
```

so I tried the `apt --fix-broken install` but that had errors too:

```
jeff@haran-linux:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 libllvm7 libllvm7:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-cfg1-390 libnvidia-compute-390 libnvidia-compute-390:i386 libnvidia-decode-390 libnvidia-decode-390:i386 libnvidia-encode-390
  libnvidia-encode-390:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-390
  libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-390 nvidia-dkms-390 nvidia-driver-390 nvidia-kernel-source-390 nvidia-utils-390
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnvidia-cfg1-390 libnvidia-compute-390 libnvidia-compute-390:i386 libnvidia-decode-390 libnvidia-decode-390:i386 libnvidia-encode-390
  libnvidia-encode-390:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-390 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386
  nvidia-compute-utils-390 nvidia-dkms-390 nvidia-driver-390 nvidia-kernel-source-390 nvidia-utils-390 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390
17 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 84.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 149 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 nvidia-driver-390 amd64 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [394 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libnvidia-gl-390 amd64 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [14.3 MB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 nvidia-dkms-390 amd64 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [28.2 kB]
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 nvidia-kernel-source-390 amd64 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [8,568 kB]
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libnvidia-decode-390 amd64 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [1,121 kB]
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main i386 libnvidia-decode-390 i386 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [1,190 kB]
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main i386 libnvidia-compute-390 i386 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [21.0 MB]
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libnvidia-compute-390 amd64 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [20.6 MB]
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 nvidia-compute-utils-390 amd64 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [70.4 kB]
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main i386 libnvidia-encode-390 i386 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [54.6 kB]
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libnvidia-encode-390 amd64 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [54.3 kB]
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 nvidia-utils-390 amd64 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [327 kB]
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390 amd64 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [1,617 kB]
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libnvidia-cfg1-390 amd64 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [71.9 kB]
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main i386 libnvidia-fbc1-390 i386 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [40.2 kB]
Get:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libnvidia-fbc1-390 amd64 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [43.3 kB]
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libnvidia-ifr1-390 amd64 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [70.9 kB]
Get:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main i386 libnvidia-ifr1-390 i386 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [64.0 kB]
Get:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main i386 libnvidia-gl-390 i386 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 [14.9 MB]
Fetched 84.5 MB in 26s (3,290 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 177663 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-nvidia-driver-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-driver-390 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-libnvidia-gl-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-390'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-lvXGM8/01-libnvidia-gl-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-390:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../02-nvidia-dkms-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking nvidia-dkms-390 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-nvidia-kernel-source-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-source-390 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-libnvidia-decode-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libnvidia-decode-390:amd64 (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Unpacking libnvidia-decode-390:i386 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libnvidia-decode-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-decode-390:amd64 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-libnvidia-compute-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libnvidia-compute-390:i386 (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-390:amd64 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-libnvidia-compute-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-390:i386 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-nvidia-compute-utils-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-compute-utils-390 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-libnvidia-encode-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libnvidia-encode-390:i386 (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Unpacking libnvidia-encode-390:amd64 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-libnvidia-encode-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-encode-390:i386 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-nvidia-utils-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-utils-390 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-libnvidia-cfg1-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-cfg1-390:amd64 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../14-libnvidia-fbc1-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Unpacking libnvidia-fbc1-390:amd64 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../15-libnvidia-fbc1-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../16-libnvidia-ifr1-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../17-libnvidia-ifr1-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-ifr1-390:amd64 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) over (390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../18-libnvidia-gl-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-390'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-lvXGM8/18-libnvidia-gl-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-390:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-lvXGM8/01-libnvidia-gl-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-lvXGM8/18-libnvidia-gl-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
jeff@haran-linux:~$
```

Couple of days later... Just thought I'd wrap this up. I ended up reinstalling 18.04 from an installation DVD I burned from the latest ISO. I appreciate the suggestions that were made but it seems that once one's PC gets into this "The package system is broken" state there's no way out of it short of reinstalling everything. At least the suggestions provided were not sufficient to repair the system.

So here's what I take from this experience. If one uses the NVidia driver, it becomes possible for a system update from Ubuntu to result in the installation of a kernel that is not compatible with the driver. And once that happens, there doesn't seem to be any easy recovery short of reinstalling the whole system. And since the latest Ubuntu installation DVD no longer contains an option to reinstall the existing system without wiping the contents of the /home directory too, that reinstallation can turn into a quite time consuming process (it took me most of 2 days to copy the contents of my home off to another computer and then restore it from that other computer following the reinstall, I have a lot of photos on my PC).

So going forward if I am presented with a system update from Ubuntu that includes a new kernel I am going to flip my system back to using the Nouveau driver first. You might want to do the same.

Note that I have not yet attempted to upgrade and install the newer NVidia driver yet. I am hoping that if it turns out to be incompatible with the new kernel that my PC won't end up in the same "The package system is broken" state. At least this time if it does I already have my /home backed up, so the restoration should take less than the 2 days.

Thanks to the responders who tried to help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

Recently the kernel has been upgraded to 5.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.

The 390.116 from the official reposiories doesn't build with the 5.3 kernel.

You can fix it by installing 390.129 Nvidia drivers from a PPA. Run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
sudo apt upgrade
```

Reboot and all should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue. Laptop does not detect 2nd monitor. Nvidia-smi returns following error:

"nvidia-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."

It works after I tried:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to disable "secure boot" in bios. Nvidia drivers dont like it.